# AWS VPN Client on Ubuntu (18.04 — 23.04) and Debian (8 — 12, sid): Unknown error ocurred

Tags: debian, ubuntu, vpn, aws

I've tried to launch AWS Client VPN on all Ubuntu releases, starting with 18.04 and up to 23.04 an everywhere I got `Unknown error ocurred. Try again.`.
I've tried to launch it on all releases of Debian starting with 8 and up to 12 and sid and got the same error — `Unknown error ocurred. Try again.`.

(yes `ocurred`, not `occurred`)

Is ther any solution to launch AWS Client VPN on any Linux Distro?

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the very same issue.

The Amazon VPN is OpenVPN but federated connections (f.x. where Azure AD is the ultimate identity provider) require the AWS VPN client.

Tried all tricks I could find online and eventually ended up using non-federated VPN auth with `openvpn --config nonfedconfig.ovpn`. It's definitely not sustainable but will do for now as we're only a handful of people using Ubuntu 23.04.

This is not a solution but a workaround until a proper solution is found...